# Curl request with proxy. how verify if it work?

Tags: curl, proxy

I'm trying to do a curl request to a website with a proxy in the option and it seems it works. But how can I verify if the website receive the proxy IP? I have installed Fiddler but it isn't helping me.
Any suggestion? I want to see if the website see my IP or the proxy IP. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

## Variant 1: External Service httpbin.org

You might use http://httpbin.org which allows you to display all the HTTP-headers from your request. The website has some nice examples using curl.

```
curl http://httpbin.org/get
```

would return for example all headers and the origin IP.

## Variant 2: Capturing network traffic

If you do not want to trust an external service you would need to capture all network traffic. You would need to run this either on the machine running the proxy or the webserver. This is because you obviously cannot capture what the proxy sends to the webserver from the client.

### Analysis and capture using Wireshark

Wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org) is the tool you need to capture and analyse any network traffic. If your machine has a graphical user interface you can use it to capture network traffic, otherwise use tcpdump (see below)

Select an interface (e.g. your WIFI or Ethernet interface) and start the capture, you should see any network activity scrolling by in the main window.

In order to filter for HTTP-traffic just enter "http" in the "filter" input box above and click "Apply". You should be vary about headers such as "X-Forwarded-for" which, depending on the proxy's configuration, might reveal the client's IP address.
It might be helpful to further filter the data if the machine is experiencing a lot of traffic. You can filter for requests involving certain IPs with using ip.addr i.e. you could use "http and ip.addr = 1.2.3.4" to filter for HTTP-requests where either the recipient or the sender is the specified IP. Please note that this is only a display filter, so for performance reasons you might use a capture filter if you know exactly what you are looking for.

### Capturing on the command-line using tcpdump

If you are on a server without GUI, you can use the tool tcpdump to write the network traffic into a file which can be opened by Wireshark later on another machine.

```
tcpdump host 1.2.3.4 and port 80 -w traffic.pcap
```

The above would capture all traffic from/to IP 1.2.3.4 and from/to port 80 and write it to the file traffic.pcap.

Answer (score 0):

`curl -v -I http://example.com` will show you results that explain proxy usage:

```
$ curl -v -I http://example.com
* Uses proxy env variable http_proxy == 'http://67.212.186.101:80'
*   Trying 67.212.186.101:80...

* Connected to 67.212.186.101 (67.212.186.101) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```